Can't upgrade Android Studio from Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1 to Patch 2
I want to update my Android Studio version from the Android Studio Iguana | version 2023.2.1 Patch 1 becomes Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2. The patch download process was successfully carried out. When the Android Studio restart request is made, the upgrade process stops and a message appears as in the image below.

I have tried repeating the patch update process in the same way. But the conflict message still appears. How to solve this problem without uninstall and reinstall Android Studio?
